# python plot large dimension data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 1800*100000000 matrix, and I want to plot it in python using code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.spy(m)
plt.show()
```

The result is disappointing, it looks like a line because of little row number compared to column number:

[image]

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`spy()` accepts a number of keyword arguments, `aspect` in particular is interesting...](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.spy)

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [3]: a = np.random.random((25,250))>0.6
In [4]: %matplotlib
Using matplotlib backend: Qt4Agg
In [5]: plt.spy(a)
Out[5]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7f9ad1a790b8>
```

[image: standard]

```
In [6]: plt.spy(a, aspect='auto')
Out[6]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7f9ad1139d30>
```

[image]